# robocopy unable to find specified path

Tags: email, powershell, robocopy

```
#Variables
$logfile = "\\hermamora\Public\Plex Backup\Logs\Plex_Backup_Log_$(get-date -format "yyyyMMdd").txt"

function log($string, $color)
{
   if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = "white"}
   Write-Host $string -ForegroundColor $color
   $string | Out-File -Filepath $logfile -Append
}

function Main {
    robocopy Q:\ L:\ /v /mir /z /r:1 /w:5 
}
$main = Main

#Arguments for Email
$From = "FROMADDRESS"
$To = "TOADDRESS"
#$Attachment = $logfile
$Subject = "Plex Backup Success"
$Body = "Here is the log of the Plex DB Backup, It was able to complete successfully"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$login = "USERNAME"
$password = "PASSWORD" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Pscredential -Argumentlist $login,$password

#Main Script

#Sets up Drives for Easy copy
subst L: "\\hermamora\Public\Plex Backup\Backup" 
subst Q: "C:\Users\ztownes\AppData\Local\Plex Media Server"

#Stops Plex and Copies DB
taskkill /IM "Plex Media Server.exe" 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
log $main
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
Start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Server.exe" 

#Removes Drives for unclutering
subst /d L:
subst /d Q:
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

#Sends Email
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $credentials -Attachments $logfile

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

Whenever I try to run this code it is unable to find the drives L: and Q: for `robocopy`. I am able to see the drives in Windows Explorer. I have an almost identical script for PowerShell that runs this with no problem. For obvious security reasons I have removed the email addresses and passwords from the email arguments.

Comment: You set up the drives for "easy copy" well after you called Main that tried to refer to the drives.  Try moving `$main = Main` to just before the `log $main`.

Comment: Also, `subst` is for mapping local paths to drive letters. I don't think it works with UNC paths.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too, @AnsgarWiechers. `New-PsDrive`, `New-SmbMapping` or `net use` are the typical approaches for that.

Comment: So changing the $main = Main to just above where I use it seemed to complete the copy just fine. I haven't had any issue using subst for UNC paths on windows 10 but it appears that it has issues running on any server environment.